# babylon.js repeating texture seam/artifact

Tags: javascript, webgl, babylonjs

I've recently started dabbling in shader programming using babylon.js. I'm trying to write a fragment shader that supports repeating textures. I used a pretty trivial way to do it, As you can tell by the link.

[http://www.babylonjs.com/cyos/#CARU2#1](http://www.babylonjs.com/cyos/#CARU2)

```
vec2 xy = vUV;
vec2 phase = fract(xy / vec2(1.0/vScale,1.0/vScale));
vec3 color = texture2D(textureSampler, phase).rgb;
```

The problem is that this creates a strange pixelating effect on the seams of the repeating texture, as shown by the following image.

[image: My problem]

How can I fix this? It must be something wrong with my fragment shader, because using the standard material doesn't yield this problem.

If anyone could help I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Wow okay I'm an idiot, I was scaling the image in a really stupid and inefficient way. I don't think I actually understood what the line:

```
vec2 phase = fract(xy / vec2(1.0/vScale,1.0/vScale));
```

Was doing. I'm still not 100% on it, but the logical way is simply to multiply the uv vector by the repeating factor.

```
vec2 phase = vec2(xy.x*vScale,xy.y*vScale);
```

You can see the result here:

http://www.babylonjs.com/cyos/#CARU2#2